# Booting Windows 10 with bootia32.efi on a 64-bit UEFI System

Tags: uefi, windows-10, bootable-media

I have downloaded Windows 10 AIO disk but it has only the **bootia32.efi**which can be booted only 32-bit Systems & not on 64-bit. I have browsed around the internet and found some suggestions that the **bootmgw.efi** can be taken either from an existing 64-bit installation or extracted from **install.wim** present in a 64-bit install iso and then renamed to the required **bootx64.efi**.

Is this possible ? And if so, Can I know the exact procedure to go about doing this if it is different from simply extracting and then renaming the file ?

Comment: It's very difficult -- perhaps even impossible -- to install a 32-bit version of Windows on a system with a 64-bit EFI, or vice-versa, at least in EFI mode. Your best bet is to obtain an installation medium that matches your firmware's bit depth.

Comment: No, It is an AIO disk which has both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The only problem is that it has a 32-bit EFI only instead of both 32-bit and 64-bit EFI thus making the iso unbootable on 64-bit systems.

Comment: By "EFI," I think you mean "EFI boot loader." The EFI is the firmware in your computer; what's on the disk is not the EFI. If the medium supposedly supports both 32- and 64-bit installations but is lacking the 64-bit boot loader, then it is defective, and you should contact whoever distributes it. (I don't know what "AIO" means in this context. Is that an OEM-provided disk image?) It should be possible to add a 64-bit boot loader by extracting it from other files, but I don't know the precise procedure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded a counterfeit ISO image. The genuine x64 Windows 10 does not have `bootia32.efi` — that file is belong to the x86 version.

Replace that with a genuine x64 image from Microsoft which you can get from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) and you’re good to go. Note that “English” is en-US while “English International” is en-GB.

(Ignore the “Tech Bench Upgrade” babble — I have linked to this site because the regular one directs you to the online installer if it detects Windows, while from the “Tech Bench” one you can download just the ISOs directly regardless of browser.)

Comment: Also might mention that the reason Microsoft offers Windows available to download for free is because: 1) You're paying for the *licence* and not the actual software. 2) Pirated versions can include nasty stuff such as keyloggers and spyware.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are writing is nonsense. The 32-bit version of Windows has the bootloader bootia32.efi, while the 64-bit version has the bootx64.efi. He does NOT have a counterfeit version of Windows but the wrong Windows version. Most modern system need the 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi Microsoft does not distribute an “AIO” image containing both x86 and x64 versions.

Comment: @kinokijuf Not sure what AIO means, but I just created myself a Windows 20H2 iso that contains both the x64 Windows as well as the x86 version (8GB big). It works for installing the x64 version. When selecting the x86 version, you get an error message with some file being wrong. Sure MS messed it up again, but the files are there and if one would extract those files - I'm sure - one could install the x86 version of Windows. That iso contains both bootx64.efi and bootia32.efi.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi you created it yourself. Microsoft does not distribute such iso's.

Comment: @kinokijuf when you go to MS website to download iso, it downloads a program. You start that program in Windows and it asks you what you would like to download (x86, x64 or both) and if you like to have it as "iso" or written to a USB. Did I now "create" myself a counterfeit ISO image? I think it's official MS iso!